# Trouble processing "javax" error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, javax.crypto

So im not sure what happened here. While attempting to integrate login page and doing some work to get PlayClient updated to GoogleApiClient things started to get buggy. After getting my program to be "error free" i ran it and instantly was faced with the error below.  but i did some research, i am not explicitly calling the SealedObject class. I removed the dependencies one by one and Android Studio didn't even realize i did this and big surprise this didn't help solve the issue.  There was a thing i read about updating to 2.0 from 1.6 or vice versa but im pretty sure i never touched that setting. been dealing with this for about 4 hours now and im starting to get a little concerned that I 100% irreparably broke the build. any help is appreciated.

There is a part in the grade output that alludes to a solution but i have no idea where to start.  it states "No matching client found for package name 'saberapplications.recyclerviewtutorial"

This is the gradle output.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugGoogleServices
No matching client found for package name 'saberapplications.recyclerviewtutorial'
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug
trouble processing "javax/crypto/SealedObject.class":
Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.
This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.
However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality.
If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
building an application, then be forewarned that your application
will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
system. You will be to blame for this problem.
If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 1.257 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

This is the Gradle.build (app) file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "saberapplications.recyclerviewtutorial"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/okio-1.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/okhttp-1.2.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0'
}
```

This is the Project Gradle file.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

This is my Manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="saberapplications.recyclerviewtutorial">
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<permission
    android:name="saberapplications.recyclerviewtutorial.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="saberapplications.recyclerviewtutorial.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<!--
 To retrieve OAuth 2.0 tokens or invalidate tokens to disconnect a user. This disconnect
 option is required to comply with the Google+ Sign-In developer policies
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/pplogo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".profilepage"
        android:label="PawPads">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.profilepage" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.example.provenlogic1.myapplication" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />

    <activity
        android:name=".ChatActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_chat"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name="saberapplications.projectlocal.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"></activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Comment: are you using import to javax.* classes?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Gradle output:

```
advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.
```

you must remember that:

> **javax.* packages aren't available to Android.**

Comment: i know this. im not using any code that uses javax.*  something is likely screwed up with my settings.

Comment: it is very likely this key term in the gradle output: "No matching client found for package name"

is the culprit but i have no idea where to start troubleshooting this.